# Почему не создается список?

Tags: python, list, список

```
l = [1, 2, 3]

l1 = l.append(4)

print(l)

print(l1)

out: [1, 2, 3, 4]

out: None
```

Вроде бы создаю новый список `(l1)` из `l`.
Не очень понятно почему первый список изменился  а второй оказался пустым.
По идее первый список не должен меняться, ведь создается новый объект.

Answer (score 5):

Так нельзя присваивать списки, есть два типа
Первое это просто присвоить такое же значение списку, но тогда программа будет больше занимать оперативной памяти
Так что если вам надо просто ссылаться на этот список и ничего с ним не делать то рекомендую использовать ссылки

```
l1 = l
```

Но тогда при таком условие будет `True`:

```
l1 is l
out: True
```

Чтобы такого не произошло вам надо присвоить такое же значение, но это скажется на производительности:

```
l1 = l[:]

l1 is l
out: False
```

### Дополнение

Функция `.append` добавляет в список то что вы напишите в прямом смысле
Например:

```
l = [1,2,3]
l1 = [2,3,4]
l.append(l1)
print(l)
out: [1, 2, 3, [2, 3, 4]]
```

Но если вы хотите сделать такое:
`[1,2,3,2,3,4]`
То тогда вам понадобиться функция `.extend` она уже работает чуть иначе и не добавляет всё в одну ячейку массива, а питается разложить на разные ячейки

Comment: Как-то вы немного путано объясняете. Почти правильно, но надо тщательнее всё-таки. Например, копирование списка вы называете наследованием. И всю дорогу у вас так.

Comment: Простите, буду знать. В следующий раз буду вспоминать ваш совет перед опубликацией ответа.

Comment: Ну просто проверяйте, что пишете, и старайтесь чётче формулировать. Вот к примеру взятие слайса от всего списка `l1 = l[:]` - это копирование списка (т.е. тоже самое, что `list(l)`), а не присваивание ссылки, `l1 is l` не будет после этого `True`.

Comment: А простите, я просто етот кусок кода с книги смотрел.

Comment: Так то вы молодец, продолжайте, всё будет хорошо

Answer (score 4):

`.append` возвращает `None` и меняет исходный список.
Вот как например можно сделать то, что вы хотите:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
l1 = l + [4]
print(l)
print(l1)
```